# QuillJS Editor - Rotate upload image inside editor or before upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, quill

I try to upload picture which have in exif data wrong orientation parameter. This causes that image is rotate incorrectly.

I need to rotate image before upload to quillJS editor.

**How can I do this? Any idea?**

Edit:

`.js`

```
app.config(['ngQuillConfigProvider', function (ngQuillConfigProvider) {
  var toolbarModules = [                
            ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],        // toggled buttons
            ['blockquote'],

            [{ 'list': 'ordered' }, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
            [{ 'indent': '-1' }, { 'indent': '+1' }],          // outdent/indent

            ['clean'],                                         // remove formatting button

            ['link', 'image', 'video']                         // link and image, video
        ];
  var toolbarFormats = ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike', 'blockquote', 'clean', 'list', 'link', 'image', 'video'];
  ngQuillConfigProvider.set({
    toolbar: toolbarModules
  }, undefined, 'Placeholder', toolbarFormats, undefined, undefined);
}]);
```

`.html`

```
<ng-quill-editor ng-model="data.description" toolbar="true" link-tooltip="true" image-tooltip="false" toolbar-entries="size bold list bullet italic underline strike align link" error-class="input-error"></ng-quill-editor>
```

Comment: Provide your code, please.

Comment: I've added code

Answer (score 0):

i got solution.

include this, 
https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js

and then, write follow codes into quill.js: line 70744.

```
    node.onload = function () {
      EXIF.getData(node, function() {
        var allMetaData = EXIF.getAllTags(this);
        switch (allMetaData.Orientation) {
          case 1: // The 0th row is at the visual top of the image, and the 0th column is the visual left-hand side. 
            break;
          case 2: // The 0th row is at the visual top of the image, and the 0th column is the visual right-hand side.
            node.style.transform = "rotateY(180deg)";
            break;
          case 3: // The 0th row is at the visual bottom of the image, and the 0th column is the visual right-hand side. 
            node.style.transform = "rotateY(360deg) rotate(180deg)";
            break;
          case 4: // Toe 0th row is at the visual bottom of the image, and the 0th column is the visual left-hand side. 
            node.style.transform = "rotateX(180deg)";
            break;
          case 5: // The 0th row is the visual left-hand side of the image, and the 0th column is the visual top. 
            node.style.transform = "rotateY(180deg) rotate(90deg)";
            break;
          case 6: // The 0th row is the visual right-hand side of the image, and the 0th column is the visual top. 
            node.style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
            break;
          case 7: // The 0th row is the visual right-hand side of the image, and the 0th column is the visual bottom. 
            node.style.transform = "rotateY(180deg) rotate(270deg)";
            break;
          case 8: // The 0th row is the visual left-hand side of the image, and the 0th column is the visual bottom.
            node.style.transform = "rotate(270deg)";
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      });
    }
```

> quill.js: line 70744.

you can get follow cdn. i think it's latest version.
https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js

Answer (score 0):

i got another solution.
maybe it's better than before i think.
before solution is just only changing the viewing by style sheet.
but, this time you can rewrite image data correctly via canvas.
it has only one demerit, when selected huge size image, we need long time for rewriting image data.

first, include this library
https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image

and then, 
rewrite original quill.js
comment out line 10744

```
// node.setAttribute('src', this.sanitize(value));
```

and add in follow codes

```
loadImage(
    value,
    function (canvas) {
      node.setAttribute('src', canvas.toDataURL());
    },
    {
      orientation: true
    }
);
```